# Problem with grid having different gap size

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have on div that uses display grid, i dont know whats its happening but as you can see, theres more gap space on each 2x2 rows, i need that all the items have the same gap.

JS:

```
<div className={styles.inventory}>
   {array.map(item => (
     <div className={styles.slot} />
   ))}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inventory {
    max-height: 30em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 7em);
    gap: 0.1em; 
    background-color: var(--background-color);
}

.slot {
    height: 7em;
    width: 7em;
    background-color: var(--slot-color);
}
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Please add the relevant error as text to your question-body by editing - links to images might become stale..

Comment: Hello, the error is visual, i cannot add text :( @iLuvLogix

Answer (score -1):

Try making the column gap an absolute value like `gap: 1px;`.